# Can't create Android SDK25(7.1) virtual device. (VS mac)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device, visual-studio-macros

I already understand that I should download a right System image to use Android virtual device.

And it works fine on SDK24(7.0).
I downloaded SDK 24 and Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image.
I am able to create SDK 24 AVD and works fine.

But I tried same with SDK25.
I downloaded SDK 25 and Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image.
But when I try to create AVD by selecting Device on the list and set Target as "Android 7.1.1 - API Level 25"

Then, CPU/ABI section says "No system images installed for this target".
I tried to change 'Device' on the list.

None of them works.

Comment: Have you tried x86 (not x86-64) system image? For my, x64 images never worked actually, while 32-bit ones are alwyas fine.

Comment: I tried it but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same issue.

My solution : I installed Android Studio and have it pointing to my Xamarin SDK location.  I use Android Studio to create and start my emulators.  Visual Studio for Mac is quite happy to deploy to them, once they are running.  It seems to be a bug in VS4Mac.  I also cheat and use Android Studio to do my XML in and then copy & paste it to VS4Mac.

Comment: @BrightLee I'd be quite interested to know if it works for you as well.  I just had to change the Android Studio SDK path to point to my Xamarin Android SDK location.

Comment: I really appreciate it..!!! It works like a charm. At the beginning of the installation process, it asks "standard" or "customize". I choose to 'customize' and set android SDK location to Xamarin android SDK location. Works beautifully. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrightLee - I also use the layout designer in Android Studio and then copy & paste the XML across to VStudio - I find AS to be a lot slicker at the moment.

Comment: I only make an app with using XF but it's good to know. Thanks again.

Comment: @BrightLee - Ah, I see - nice.  I hope they fix the Xamarin bug soon, it's pretty annoying.